Is it possible to define UserControl based on DataGridTemplateColumn in WPF
Is it possible to define UserControl based on DataGridTemplateColumn?
I would like to define a TextBoxDataGridTemplateColumn, ComboBoxDataGridTemplateColumn, DatePickerDataGridTemplateColumn, etc. to reduce code among several DataGrid. Ideally, I would also like to add several DependencyProperty such as RightBorder=True, etc.
I've found that I can share XAML and code-behind, but I'm not sure sure that I can define an actual UserControl since I can't add a section DataGridTemplateColumn.Resources where I would like to define several styles, context menu, etc.
Is it because DataGridTemplateColumn derived from DependencyObject unlike DataGrid for example which derived from Control?

I am not sure what you're trying to do here but it sounds like you want to create custom data grid column with User Control as it's template? Have a look at this SO question

It sounds like extending DataGridColumn or DataGridTemplateColumn would be more natural.
